# arraylist rearrange with another arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, position

I want to ask about arraylist rearrange

If I have 2 arraylist like this

```
ArrayList<A> listA;
ArrayList<B> listB;
```

And if I rearrange listA like this

```
private static class Descending implements Comparator<A> {
    @Override
    public int compare(A arrayListA, A t1) {
        return t1.getLasttime().compareTo(arrayListA.getLasttime());
    }
}

private void setListTimeSort(ArrayList<A> arrayListA) {
    Descending descending = new Descending();
    Collections.sort(arrayListA, descending);
}
```

I want to change position together listB.

simple example:

```
listA before = 1, 2, 3, 4
listB before = a, b, c, d
```

If listA change = 2, 1, 4, 3, I want to listB change same position item = b, a, d, c.

I changed listA, but I don't know how I can change listB (change position like listA).

Comment: Parallel lists are a bit of an antipattern, and suggest that instead you should use a class (or record) to hold the A and B values, and populate a single list with instances of that class. In this solution there is only one list to sort, and A and B are available together.

Answer (score 0):

This clearly assumes that both lists are the same size.

I would create a new `List<Pair<A,B>>`, you could then iterate the lists creating a `Pair` object from items in ListA, and ListB in the same position.

Then sort your list of Pairs (the `List<Pair<A,B>>`) using a comparator that compares the `getKey()` part of the pair.

Then iterate the sorted list, creating a List of the `getValue()` part of the pair.

(I'd probably use streams, but that is the basic idea)

Comment: maybe your solution will worked for me.. but, can you give me simple example..? i searched about 'pair'. but i can't understand.. :(

Comment: i found solution aready. but i don't know where i can share